# Set-Logic in Z3 .NET API

Tags: c#, z3

How do I use set-logic when using the .NET API function .parseSmtlib2String(String) when using Z3 version 3.1?

I always end up with a Z3Error-Exception.

Isn't it necessary in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the command `(set-logic <symbol>)` is not supported when using the API `parseSmtlib2String`.

We have this limitation because of technical reasons.
In the textual interface, the command `set-logic` can only be used before the context is initialized. The context is initialized based on the selected logic. When the API `parseSmtlib2String` is used the context has already been initialized by the user. So, the command `set-logic` fails, and generates a parsing error.

I acknowledge this is not the ideal behavior. I will investigate alternatives.