# Set Logic / Options in Scala^Z3

Tags: scala, z3

I can't figure out, how to set a logic and the according options in Scala^Z3. 
Guess its really simple, but I just can't find it.. so I really would appreciate some help there ;)

Regards,
Florian

ps.: Scala 3.2 and Z3 4.0 work really fine together :)

Comment: And what is "Scala 3.2"?

Comment: I ment this setting:

res0: String = Z3 4.0 (build 0, rev. 0), ScalaZ3 3.2.c (in dev.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are still looking...

There are two ways to set options:

1. Pass the parameters when you construct your `Z3Config` instance, e.g. `new Z3Config("MODEL" -> true)`.
2. Call `.setParamValue` on a `Z3Config` instance, e.g. `myConf.setParamValue("MODEL", true)`.

Now to answer the particular question on how to set the *logic*, that is unfortunately not supported by Z3's API. You can take a look at Leo's answer to [this similar question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344639/set-logic-in-z3-net-api).

Note that strictly speaking you don't really need that option when using the API, though: all theories can be used and Z3 will magically figure out what to do.